# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to use the AsyncTask class on android but I have a problem.

Here is my code:

```
 public void CheckIfUserIsLogedIn ()
{
    int userPresence = localDatabase.CheckUserPresence();
    if (userPresence == 0) 
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new checkCountryAsync().execute();
    }
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.userlogedon);
    }
}  

class checkCountryAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute(); 
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int countryPresence = localDatabase.CheckCountryPresence();
        if (countryPresence == 0) 
        {
            CountryTable country = new CountryTable() ;
            country.EnterCountry();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't know where I am doing something wrong. The method CheckCountryPresence() from the LocalDatabase class is only making a query and returns a result.

Thank you.

Edit: Here is the logCat:

```
02-20 08:41:25.804: W/dalvikvm(26458): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:717)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at milos.mdpi.CountryTable.<init>(CountryTable.java:5)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at milos.mdpi.MDPIActivity$checkCountryAsync.doInBackground(MDPIActivity.java:367)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at milos.mdpi.MDPIActivity$checkCountryAsync.doInBackground(MDPIActivity.java:1)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
02-20 08:41:25.834: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: looks to me that the problem is at line 5 of country table, not inside the AsyncTask!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you are doing some stuff to `Update` your UI from a `Non-UI` thread. So, you should put your stuff to update the UI inside `runOnUiThread()` so that it executes the stuff on your UI hread itself.

**UPDATE:**

Just try to put your stuff for getting `CheckCountryPresence();` inside `onPreExecute()`. So your edited class should be like,

```
class checkCountryAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    int countryPresence = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       countryPresence = localDatabase.CheckCountryPresence();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {

        Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (countryPresence == 0) 
            {
              CountryTable country = new CountryTable() ;
              country.EnterCountry();
            }
        }
    });
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Lalit, but I am not updating my UI from the AsyncTask. I am only working with a query on my local database and doing some operations showed in the code above.

Comment: You should add the logcat(error) out with your question to get better idea.

Comment: Great, it is much better now, I have no exceptions. But still a litle problem is there, I am doing this operation at the begining of my application and I have a black screen until this operation is not finished. Something like my view is not set and I am trying to set it on pre execute but nothing.

Comment: You can add a progressdialog in onPreExecute and dismiss it in onPostExecute.

Comment: In fact, I would only to have a setContentView(R.layout.main); and doing the country adding on bacground, that's the reason I used the AsyncTask

Comment: No idea how to do this @Lalit?

Comment: yeah I know what you want to do, you can just add progressdialog as I said.

Comment: Thanks but how to do this and to set the setContentView() ?

Comment: inside the onPostExecute you can invalidate/update your view.

Comment: Ok but I would like to set my View onPreExecute. When I qm doing setContentView, nothing hapens. How to use the  add progressdialog? It's the first time I am working with the AsyncTask's and I don't understand how to realy use it.

Comment: Well you should see some tutorials for sure, you are asking very simple things that you can learn from any tutorial.

Comment: Thank you @Lalit, but I already used some tutorials for understanding how to use AsyncTasks. I know that this class gives me some methods like onPreExecute, onPostexecute etc. But, the problem is that I don't understand why the setOncontentView does not work onPreExecute. I have tryed with something like showDialog(R.layout.main);  but nothing

Answer (score 3):

Has your CountryTable class any interaction with the UI activity/class? Even fetching new rows for your adapter object?
If yes, you cannot update your activity from outside the activity itself.

Fortunately you can overcome this pretty easily once you figure out the solution ;)

step 1:

Define an interface, like `CheckCountryCallback` with a single method called `onCheckCountryFinished(String taskResult)`;

Step 2: let the activity which call your asynctask implement this interface and its method.

Step 3: define a constructor for your asyncTask with a single parameter of type CheckCountryCallback

Step 4: override onPostExecute of your AT, and simply write mCaller.onCheckCountryFinished(result).

This is not enough sadly because you'd still be updating the ui from another thread but we're getting close!

In your implemented onCheckCountryFinished you should redirect the call to a handler you've to define in your activity. Send a message to that handler and you can update the UI (or the adapter or whatnot) from the handle message method of the handler.

Handler example:

```
private static final int UPDATE = 2;
private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == UPDATE) {
               //do something with m.obj
               myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

callback example

```
public void onCheckCountryFinished(String result){
    Message m = Message.obtain();
    m.what = UPDATE;
    m.obj = result;
    handler.sendMessage(m);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing your AsyncTask anything so make the parameters of AsyncTask all Void like this `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` then change `doInBackground` to this `protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)`. Also, get rid of the `onPreExecute` method since you are not even using it.

Also, it is unclear with you code provided, but `CheckIfUserIsLogedIn` needs to be called from the UI thread. AsyncTask is really only meant to be run off of the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you @koopaking3 but still the sqme problem.

Comment: Probably a problem with what you are doing in this part of the code then `CountryTable country = new CountryTable();` and `country.EnterCountry();`. They probably are trying to do something outside of the Activity that AsyncTask is in. Perhaps post the code for these as well or describe to us what they perform?

Comment: You could make `country.EnterCountry();` just return some data and use that to update the UI in `onPostExecute`...it's hard to tell because it is not clear what they do exactly but this would be a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

one of the problem that i faced, `simpleCursorAdapter` also returns same error of `looper` when called from `thread`. So to remove that error, inside thread

```
ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
   String[] FROM = {/*your data here*/};
int[] TO = { /*your data here*/ };
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ActivityName.this, R.layout.row, cursor, FROM, TO);   
listTimeline.setAdapter(adapter); //your own code here.
}
});
```